# LINQ Projection AFTER optional parameter filtering

Tags: c#, linq, projection

I have this function in a class:

```
public IEnumerable<PedidosList> Pedidos_Listar(string sComprobante, Clientes MyCliente = null, DateTime? dDesde = null, DateTime? dHasta = null, bool bCumplidos = false)
{           
    using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
    {
        IEnumerable<PedidosList> query =
            from Pedidos in context.Pedidos
            join Clientes in context.Clientes on Pedidos.ID_Cliente equals Clientes.ID_Cliente
            where Pedidos.ID_Comprobante == sComprobante                    
            select new PedidosList {ID_Pedido = Pedidos.ID_Pedido, Fecha=Pedidos.Fecha, Aprobado=Pedidos.Aprobado, Bruto=Pedidos.Bruto, Cliente=Clientes.RazonFantasia, 
                FechaEntrega=Pedidos.FechaEntrega, Neto=Pedidos.Neto, Numero=Pedidos.Numero, Observaciones=Pedidos.Observaciones, Entregado=Pedidos.Entregado, ID_Cliente=Pedidos.ID_Cliente };

        if (MyCliente != null) query = query.Where(i => i.ID_Cliente == MyCliente.ID_Cliente);
        if (MyCliente != null) query = query.Where(i => i.ID_Cliente == MyCliente.ID_Cliente);
        if (dDesde != null && dHasta != null) query = query.Where(i => i.Fecha >= dDesde && i.Fecha <= dHasta);
        if (bCumplidos == false) query = query.Where(i => i.Entregado == false);                
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

The idea is to use LINQ projection to fill a custom class object where multiple optional filter parameters are evaluated. My question is: For performance and encapsulation reasons, can I make the projection AFTER optional where filters are applied? In my code the projection is done BEFORE, so i can only filter by the fields on my custom class, but i want to filter over the original class fields. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can. What's the issue when you try doing so?

Comment: I don't know how. What i need is to make the SELECT NEW PedidosList AFTER add the aditional WHERE clausule. I supose need to find a way to add optional filters to linq INSIDE the LINQ statement, but i don't know if thats possible.Also I define query as IEnumerable<PedidosList> so the filter is applied once the object is already created. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query =
    from Pedidos in context.Pedidos
    join Clientes in context.Clientes on Pedidos.ID_Cliente equals Clientes.ID_Cliente
    where Pedidos.ID_Comprobante == sComprobante      
    select new { Pedidos, Clientes };              

if (MyCliente != null)
{
    query = query.Where(i => i.Pedidos.ID_Cliente == MyCliente.ID_Cliente);
    query = query.Where(i => i.Periodos.ID_Cliente == MyCliente.ID_Cliente);
}
if (dDesde != null && dHasta != null)
    query = query.Where(i => i.Pedidos.Fecha >= dDesde && i.Pedidos.Fecha <= dHasta);
if (bCumplidos == false)
    query = query.Where(i => i.Pedidos.Entregado == false);      

return (from x in query
        let Pedidos = x.Pedidos
        let Clientes = x.Clientes
        select new PedidosList {ID_Pedido = Pedidos.ID_Pedido, Fecha=Pedidos.Fecha, Aprobado=Pedidos.Aprobado, Bruto=Pedidos.Bruto, Cliente=Clientes.RazonFantasia, FechaEntrega=Pedidos.FechaEntrega, Neto=Pedidos.Neto, Numero=Pedidos.Numero, Observaciones=Pedidos.Observaciones, Entregado=Pedidos.Entregado, ID_Cliente=Pedidos.ID_Cliente
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Just a Detail: the query is only send to database when i do ToList() right? also the custom class is created only after the query was execute and return the filtered data? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's right. With your previous approach, all the `Where` filtering was executed as LINQ to Objects query, because you declared `query` as `IEnumerable<T>`. With my code, all the conditions and projections will be done by DB, which should be much faster.

Comment: I see! Perfect! That's what i was worried about. Thank you again.

Comment: Can i ask one more question about this function? Is there a reason why properties appear on IENumerable Order alphabetical instead of the class definition order? I post a question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735932/why-ienumerable-tolist-return-fields-in-alphabetical-order?noredirect=1#comment34652923_22735932

Comment: Yes, but as you can see in the image i just add the problem also happend when i put the data to a datagrid using MVVM pattern...